# Perfect Number Check

Tags: c, function, scope

So the idea behind my code is to create a program that uses functions to check and print all perfect numbers between 1 and 1000. I've come up with this, but the issue is that nothing prints. It builds successfully, runs, and exits.

I've gone through my code 3-4 times and I can't find the gap in logic, so I'm thinking its a variable definition issue, something to do with how in-scope certain functions are. Would anyone have any input for why my program is failing to recognize a perfect number, and then print it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

/*
 * 
 */

void perfectNumCheck(int num);
void perfectNumPrint (int perfectNum);

int main(void) {

    int i;
    for (i = 1; 1 <= 1000; i++)
        perfectNumCheck(i);

}

void perfectNumCheck(int num) {

    int i;
    int temp = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0)
            temp += i;
    }

    if (temp == num)
        perfectNumPrint(num);

}

void perfectNumPrint(int perfectNum) {

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < perfectNum; i++) 
        if (perfectNum % i == 0) 
            printf ("%d, ", i);

    printf("are factors of the perfect number %d.\n", perfectNum);

}
```

Comment: `for (i = 1; 1 <= 1000; i++)` - one is always less or equal than a thousand.

Comment: `if (num % i == 0)` you are dividing by zero.

Comment: ...and the same here `if (perfectNum % i == 0)` divide by zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo here:

```
for (i = 1; 1 <= 1000; i++)
    perfectNumCheck(i);
```

Should be

```
for (i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
    perfectNumCheck(i);
```

Also, you're dividing by zero.  Change all your `i = 0` in your for loops to `i = 1`

Comment: thanks friend, no surprise it had trouble running. But its still refusing to print, so there's a logic hole somewhere here.

Comment: Brilliant, much obliged. I'm not sure why that would stop the loop though, one iteration wouldn't produce results but why wouldn't it keep going and print whatever it came up with as soon as it started incrementing it?

Comment: Because you can't divide by zero, which is what you were attempting to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean perfectNum(int currentNum) {

    int i, sum = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < currentNum; i++) 
        if (perfectNum % i == 0) 
            sum += i;

    if(sum == currentNum) return ture;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Perfect Number Test** : If the sum of all factors are equals to number itself.

```
    public static bool IsItPerfectNumber(int input)
    {
        bool IsPerfectNumber = false;
        //Validation and Find all Factore 
        List<int> myList = FindFactors(input);            
        //Sum if factor
       int sumOfFactor = SumFactor(myList);

        //Check Is Perfact Number
        if (sumOfFactor == input)    
        {
            IsPerfectNumber = true;
        }
        return IsPerfectNumber;
    }

    public static List<int> FindFactors(int input)
    {
        List<int> myList = new List<int>();

        for (int j = 1; j < input; j++)
        {
            if (input % j == 0)                  {
                myList.Add(j); 
            }
        }
        return myList;
    }

    public static int SumFactor(List<int> myList)
    {
        return myList.Sum();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
boolean perfectNum(int currentNum) {

    int i, sum = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < currentNum; i++) 
        if (perfectNum % i == 0) 
             sum += i;

    if(sum == currentNum) return ture;
    return false;

}
```